# php command line on windows

Tags: php, command-line, wamp

I'm using `php` on `WAMP`. 
I'm trying to run an external program prog.exe under directory abc which takes one numeric parameter. 
the following command on DOS command line works fine

```
c:\abc\prog.exe 1234
```

but when I do it in php script it doesn't run.

```
$val="1234";
$comm = passthru("C:\abc\prog.exe ".$val)
```

but

```
$comm = passthru("dir");
echo $comm;
```

works fine.

I'm running Windows 7.

P.S I've also tried `system()` and `shell_exec()`

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't run'? As in the prog.exe is not getting the arguments?

Comment: the page seems to be loading but nothing happens until timeout..

Comment: prog.exe is getting the argument.. it I do echo (whatever I'm passing through system) and then run it in command line, its fine..

Comment: What's your program do? If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

Comment: Answer from @Kolink should solve it :)

Comment: @sachleen The program takes a couple of seconds to execute.. so Its fine.. but it doesn't even execute.. I don't see it under processes on the server when this script is run

Answer (score 3):

`\` needs to be escaped as `\\`, or else you should use single quotes.

EITHER:

```
passthru("C:\\abc\\prog.exe ".$val);
```

OR:

```
passthru('C:\abc\prog.exe '.$val);
```

Comment: @bsdnoobz Um... I don't think so?

Comment: Or `passthru("C:/abc/prog.exe $val");`

Comment: @Kolink oops, you're right. I didn't notice the single-quote.

Comment: @Kolink Both do not work.. Can it be a permission issue or something.. What should be the equivalent of chmod in windows. Do it have to give abc.exe execution rights..

Comment: Consider running your script through PHP's CLI. That way you should be able to see anything it's doing, as well as kill it if it takes too long.

Comment: It takes a couple of seconds to run on command line.. I don't see it under the processes on the server when this php script is running.. This program doesn't even execue within php

Comment: Check your server configuration to see if it is in Safe Mode, or if there is anything blocking programs from being run.

Comment: @Kolink I checked my php.ini safe mode is off